# d3.json is not accepting the query result to plot in d3 gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg, d3.js

My problem is this. I have a d3 gantt chart which works fine at first load of data, the problem is when i query another data using my filter form. the resulting query and the json encode is ok but the d3.json is not accepting my newly result to plot in the d3 gantt chart. I used console.log to check the data and it is ok.

here is my codes for fetching d3 data

```
d3.json("json", function(error,json){ 
var tasks = [];
var taskNames = [];
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
var HANDLERID = json[i].HANDLERID;
taskNames.push(HANDLERID);

tasks.push({"startDate": new Date(json[i].START1),
        "endDate": new Date(json[i].END1),
        "taskName": HANDLERID,
        "status": json[i].VAL1 });

tasks.push({"startDate": new Date(json[i].START2),
        "endDate": new Date(json[i].END2),
        "taskName": HANDLERID,
        "status": json[i].VAL2 });

tasks.push({"startDate": new Date(json[i].START3),
        "endDate": new Date(json[i].END3),
        "taskName": HANDLERID,
        "status": json[i].VAL3 });

}

console.log(tasks);
console.log(taskNames);


tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.endDate - b.endDate;
});
var maxDate = tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate;
tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.startDate - b.startDate;
});
var minDate = tasks[0].startDate;

var format = "%Y-%b-%d";

var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).tickFormat(format);
gantt(tasks);

 });
```

here is my jquery post

```
function searching(){

var input_handlermodel = $("#input_handlermodel").val();
var input_handlerid = $("#handlerid").val();

$.post("../../mini/pm/json",
{input_handlermodel : input_handlermodel, input_handlerid : input_handlerid},
function(data){$("#result").html(data);});


}
```

this is how i json encode the resulting query

```
$sth1 = ibase_query($query);
$items = array();
 while($row1 = ibase_fetch_object($sth1) ) {
  array_push($items, $row1);
   }
 $result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: guyz it is possible for d3.json to catch a new data if i have a form then json encode the query result and plot the data at the same gantt chart?????? anybody done it before??????????

Answer (score 0):

Just try to write an update function and call it whenever you load the new data.You cant plot the different data on same gant chart unless you update the chart properly.

```
.on('click', function(d) {  

updateChart();

});
```

something like this.

Comment: base on my code sir how can i plot different data on the same gantt chart in d3 there is a gantt.redraw() i dont know how to use it. I am sorry I am a newbie in d3

Comment: function update(taskNames,format)
{
var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).tickFormat(format);
gantt(tasks);
}


call it when you again load the data from json

update(a,b);